# ng-change directive in a select is not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a select input and a function that is called when the selected value is changed. When I change the value using the keyboard arrow keys, the model isn't updated (on the first time).
Someone can tell me why?

[Here is my Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/18426/)

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function mainController($scope) {
    $scope.people = [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Julius'
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Julius Rock'
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            name: 'Christopher'
        }
    ];

    $scope.selectionChanged = function() {
        console.log('test');
    };

}
app.controller('mainController', mainController);
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="mainController">
    <!-- If you change the value with the arrows ng-change doesn't work on the first change. -->
    <select ng-model="selected" ng-options="person.name for person in people track by person.id" ng-change="selectionChanged()"></select>

    <span>{{selected}}</span>    
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: working fine here .. In mozila you have to press enter to take change else is ok

Comment: I'm using latest chrome. In Edge it works perfectly. In firefox I need press Enter, like you said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue, and in fact, is still an open one. There are a few ways to get this working how you would expect. You can read about it on the project issue tracker here: [select/ngOptions fails to update model after keyboard selection](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9134). As a workaround, you can place an empty `<option>` within your `<select>`. Observe the following change...

```
<select ng-model="selected" ng-options="person.name for person in people track by person.id" ng-change="selectionChanged()">
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/x0xzeeay/) - updated demo

Answer (score 2):

You want an autofocus on the select element, so that it starts from the first time itself. Added autofocus on select

Code Changed:

```
<select ng-model="selected" ng-options="person.name for person in people track by person.id" ng-change="selectionChanged()" autofocus></select>
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/18427/)

Comment: This still doesn't seem to update on the first keydown - latest Chrome